# Unable to replicate Wand / ImageMagick results on Ubuntu & Mac

Tags: python, ubuntu, imagemagick, wand

I am using the Wand Python ImageMagick bindings to convert a pdf document to a series of images like so:

```
from wand.image import Image

all_images = Image(filename= '/pdf/path')
for i, page in enumerate(all_images.sequences):
     with Image(page) as img:
          img.format = 'jpg'
          img.background_color = Color('white')
          img.alpha_channel = 'remove'
          img.save(filename = '/some/image/path')
```

However, I am unable to replicate exactly between a Mac & Ubuntu 14.04. For example on the Mac an image will saved at 135KB, while the Ubuntu will be slightly smaller at 100KB. These very minute differences means I am unable to reproduce my analysis, testing locally (Mac) versus deployed in production (Ubuntu).

On both machines I have `Wand==0.4.4` and `ImageMagick 7.0.7-24`

Can anyone provide a reason why I might be obtaining these differing results?

Comment: Different versions of `ghostscript` maybe, if using PDFs. Different quantisation? Different compiler version?

Comment: Check your versions of libjpeg, also. And set a common -quality for the output jpg.